# Formatting need to change for text file in bash scripting

Tags: bash

I have below output from a text file. This is long file i just copy here some rows only.

```
HP83904B74E6
13569.06
7705.509999999999
HP4DC2EECAA8
4175.1
2604.13
```

And i want to print it like below.

```
HP83904B74E6     13569.06      7705.509999999999
HP4DC2EECAA8     4175.1        2604.13
```

I have tried by reading the file line by live using while loop and try to store the value of variable e.g. `variablename$i` so that i can print it like `variablename0` and after every 3 line i have used If statement to print the value of variablename0 variablename1 variablename2, but did not work for me.

Comment: only use `paste` or `xargs` ...

Comment: did you try `awk`?

Comment: i have tried by reading the file line by live using while loop and try to store the value of variable e.g. variablename$i so that i can print it like variablename0 and after every 3  line i have used If statement to print the value of variablename0 variablename1 variablename2, but did not work for me. I am just learning bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pr`:

```
$ pr -a3t tmp.txt
HP83904B74E6        13569.06        7705.509999999999
HP4DC2EECAA8        4175.1          2604.13
```

Comment: Hi Chepner, thanks for ur valueable help , i was trying this from yesterday and after doing so much googling i ask a question here and it help me really. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> i have tried by reading the file line by live using while loop and try to store the value of variable e.g. variablename$i so that i can print it like variablename0 and after every 3 line i have used If statement to print the value of variablename0 variablename1 variablename2, but did not work for me. I am just learning bash.

```
while read -r a; do  
    read -r b; 
    read -r c; 
    echo "$a $b $c"; 
done < file
```

you get,

```
HP83904B74E6 13569.06 7705.509999999999
HP4DC2EECAA8 4175.1 2604.13
```

Comment: Thanks Jose for input i will also try this and let you know the result. Thanks again